# error: no matching member function for call to 'upper_bound' => only on macOS => Windows and Linux are fine

Tags: c++, qt, std

I'm compiling a code inspired by [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/158369/141750) with Qt Creator. Code compiles fine on Windows 10 and openSUSE Leap 15 but throws this error on macOS High Sierra:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'upper_bound'
        auto end = band.upper_bound({ 0, last->y + d });
                   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/set:692:14: note: candidate function not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'const std::__1::set<Point, std::__1::less<Point>, std::__1::allocator<Point> >::key_type' (aka 'const Point')
    iterator upper_bound(const key_type& __k)
             ^
```

My header contains:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

struct Point {
    float x{0}, y{0};

    // Used by the `set<point>` to keep the points in the band
    // sorted by Y coordinates.
    bool operator<(Point const &other) const {
        return y < other.y;
    }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, Point const &p) {
        return os << "(" << p.x << ", " << p.y << ")";
    }

};
```

My source contains:

```cpp
#include <set>

std::pair<Point, Point> nearest_pair(std::vector<Point> points)
{
    std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(),
              [](Point const &a, Point const &b) {
        return a.x < b.x;
    }
    );

    // First and last points from `point` that are currently in the "band".
    auto first = points.cbegin();
    auto last = first + 1;

    // The two closest points we've found so far:
    auto first_point = *first;
    auto second_point = *last;

    std::set<Point> band{ *first, *last };

    float d = dist(*first, *last);

    while (++last != points.end()) {
        while (last->x - first->x > d) {
            band.erase(*first);
            ++first;
        }

        auto begin = band.lower_bound({ 0, last->y - d }); // ERROR line
        auto end = band.upper_bound({ 0, last->y + d });   // ERROR line

        assert(std::distance(begin, end) <= 6);

        for (auto p = begin; p != end; ++p) {
            if (d > dist(*p, *last)) {
                first_point = *p;
                second_point = *last;
                d = dist(first_point, second_point);
            }
        }

        band.insert(*last);
    }
    return std::make_pair(first_point, second_point);
}
```

I guess I need to modify my `Point` structure, but I'm not sure how. Can anybody help?

---

### Update

Error got resolved by adding these two constructors to `Point` structure:

```cpp
    Point(){

    }

    Point(float x, float y):
        x(x)
      , y(y)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Does `Point` class have an appropriate constructor? Looks like no.

Comment: Which XCode version? Which compiler version on Windows/Linux? XCode often is not so up to date with the standard. You can try adding a `Point` (`band.upper_bound(Point{ 0, last->y + d });`)?

Comment: @vahancho No, `Point` structure doesn't have a constructor. I'll test by adding a constructor ...

Comment: @user3405291, maybe the error makes sense, then?

Comment: @vahancho Right. Let me try by adding a constructor ...

Comment: @WernerHenze XCode version is `9.4.1`

Comment: XCode 9.4.1 is old. Can you try with a newer XCode version?

Comment: @user3405291 FYI -- If you're going to use brace initializers, you could have done that on the `return` also: `return {first_point, second_point};`

Comment: @WernerHenze Right. If I run out of options, I'll download the latest XCode

Comment: @vahancho Can you post you comment regarding appropriate constructors as an answer? I added `Point()` and `Point(float x, float y)` constructors and the error on macOS got resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error clearly explains that it failed to implicitly construct an object of type `Point` out of initializer list in expression: `band.lower_bound({ 0, last->y - d })`. The error is valid, as `Point` structure doesn't have an appropriate user defined constructor for these arguments.
To solve the problem you must add a constructor that accepts two floating point arguments.

Unfortunately I don't answer the question on why other compilers do not complain. Probably the application compiled with different options.